# On Ubuntu16.04, how to run python script repeatedly - using crontab

Tags: python, cron

I would like to run python script repeatedly using crontab on Ubuntu 16.04

I run this command below on terminal.

```
$crontab -e
```

And wrote on it as follows.

```
1 * * * * python /home/elite/python/weather.py
```

I think, this does mean that run `weather.py` script every minute.

This is the `weather.py` script for testing `crontab` functionality.

```
from urllib import urlopen
import time
import re

testing = 'testing'

current_time = time.localtime()

today = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%-d-%-s', current_time)
file_name = today + ".txt"

output = open("/home/elite/python/" + file_name, "w")
output.write(testing)
```

When I run this script on the terminal - `$python weather.py`, it works well.

But `crontab` seems not working.

How can I handle it?

Comment: the 1 at the beginning means the minute of the hour, so it should run every hour, not every minute. if you want to run every minute, you need * * * * *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

First, Crontab likes the absolute path of your command. For example `/usr/bin/python`. Type `which python` to get the absolute path.

Second, `1 * * * *` is once an hour. I like to use https://crontab.guru to help get my cron times right.

Answer (score 1):

the 1 at the beginning means the minute of the hour, so it should run every hour, not every minute.

if you want to run every minute, you need `* * * * *`